# VBA Conditional Save As with Date Add

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, save-as

I am using Excel 2010 and am trying to use a macro for the following:

1. Open the Save As dialogue box
2. Take the initial file name and check IF there is an underscore followed by 8 consecutive integers (ie. _12345678) before the file type (ie. .xlsx)
3. IF that DOES EXIST remove and replace it with an underscore followed by today's date in "yyyymmdd" format (ie. _20130730) before the file type (ie. .xlsx)
4. IF that DOES NOT EXIST simply add an underscore followed by today's date in "yyyymmdd" format (ie. _20130730) before the file type (ie. .xlsx)
5. The new file name based on criteria above would be present in the File Name field in the open Save As dialogue box but the file will require user to actually save it (just naming and opening Save As.  Not actually saving with VBA)
6. Maintain whatever the original file type is

Assuming today's date is 7/30/2013, the macro would work as follows for the following beginning files:
1.) **Test File A_20130615.xlsx** would become **Test File A_20130730.xlsx**
2.) **Test File B.xlsx** would become **Test File B_20130730.xlsx**

Any and all help is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I modified a routine I have that does the same type of thing that you are trying to do, but uses the current name of the file, instead of having 2 save dialog boxes.

```
Option Explicit

Function SaveIt()

Dim CurrentFile As String
Dim FileExt As String
Dim GetFileName

CurrentFile = Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".") - 1)
FileExt = Mid(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, "."))

If InStr(CurrentFile, "_") Then
    'has underscore
    If InStrRev(CurrentFile, "_") = Len(CurrentFile) - 8 Then
        ' underscore 8 from end
        If Right(CurrentFile, 8) = CStr(Val(Right(CurrentFile, 8))) Then
            ' and it's 8 digits at the end
            CurrentFile = Left(CurrentFile, Len(CurrentFile) - 9)
            'strip the end off
        End If ' if it fails any of these tests,
    End If  'then it's not got the underscore and date
End If ' and we don't touch the filename

CurrentFile = CurrentFile & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")

GetFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(CurrentFile & FileExt)

If GetFileName <> False Then 'Cancel returns false, otherwise it returns the filename
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs GetFileName
End If

End Function
```

This also allows for people to have files named **test_1.xlsx** and **What_a_lot_of_underscores.xlsm** without having to worry about something destructing the name

Comment: Nice one, but in real life I would rather use RegEx for name capture.